# How to index twitter data in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have fetched some data from twitter using streaming api. The file has json lines corresponding to the data. I would like to index this data in elasticsearch so that it could be searched easily.

I used following command to for index

```
cat file.json | jq -c '.[] | {"index": {"_index": "bookmarks", "_type": "bookmark", "_id": .id}}, .' | curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @-
```

but it results in following error.

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:127687): Cannot index string with string "id"
```

Comment: Why the Elasticsearch tag, when the issue comes obviously of the way you are using this *jq* command line tool?

Comment: I used it because i would like to know any alternate way to index in elastic search

Comment: Can you update your post and share exactly what is the result of `cat file.json | jq -c '.[] | {"index": {"_index": "bookmarks", "_type": "bookmark", "_id": .id}}, .'`

Comment: BTW you are may be missing the `\n` character at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing all that manually, you can simply use the Logstash Twitter Input.

I wrote a [blog post](http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2015/06/01/indexing-twitter-with-logstash-and-elasticsearch/) about it.